# Programming a Native iPhone app with the web as source

Tags: php, iphone, c, native

The kind of application I am doing cannot store data in the iPhone or iPhone DB, but i need a native app that will allow a user to sign up if they haven't already, then sign in, insert things into the website database (phpmyadmin), retreive, edit, and delete data.

I am aware Objective-C is the only language you can use to do an app but how can i use the web as a source for pages/data using PHP?

Reference: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=585668

Comment: This is not a constructive question that follows the Q&A approach of StackOverflow. Please change your question to ask a technical question that can feature a specific technical answer. You need to try things and if you get an error or issue, you then ask a specific question about that issue and get an answer. Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an UIWebView as a wrapper for the app and upload it like that to the appstore.

There are also several frameworks that do something simular. The allow you to build apps using HTML + javascript + custom api

eg: http://phonegap.com/ or http://www.appcelerator.com/

Comment: Apple don't like apps that are just wrappers for websites.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an API for your site and parse responses from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Create your database in cloud. Apple is providing very good documentation for that. http://developer.apple.com/icloud/index.php